# Code::Blocks and Lapack

Tags: c++, c, windows, codeblocks, lapack

- How do you add `Lapack` libraries to `Code::Blocks` IDE on `Windows`?.
- The files I have are these: (*Victor's `Compiled binary libraries for Window`s on this page:
  http://www.stanford.edu/~vkl/code/libs.html*)

  - lapack_win32.a
  - lapack_win32.def
  - lapack_win32.dll
  - lapack_win32.exp
  - lapack_win32.lib

    - How would look like a simple example in C/C++ using the dynamic library?
      Do I use `#include <lapack>`? or how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First assuming you have installed these libraries in C:\LapackLib.

1. Click on the **Settings** Menu and then select the **Compiler** menu item.
2. From the **Compiler Settings** Dialog select the **Directories** Tab.
3. Click the **Add** button.
4. In the window that pops up type in your library path in this example it is `C:\LapackLib\`.
5. Select the **Linker**  tab
6. Repeat steps 3 and 4, then press the **Ok** button to close the **Compiler Settings** Dialog
7. Right click on your project name from the Treeview on the left hand side of the screen, it will in **bold**.
8. From the popup menu select the **Build Options** menu item
9. Select the **Linker**  tab
10. From the **Link Libraries** window, click on the **Add** button. Select the path to your library from the File Dialog, in this case it is  `C:\LapackLib\lapack_win32.lib`. Then press the **Ok** Button.
11. In your source code add the relevant include declaration

    e.g. `#include <lapack>` or `#include "lapack.h"`

For further information see the following [tutorial](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a3-using-libraries-with-codeblocks/) or the CodeBlocks [manual](http://www.codeblocks.org/docs/manual_en.pdf).