# How do I include curl library in my C project in Code Blocks (Windows)?

Tags: c++, c, windows, compiler-construction

The question seems straight forward. I tried a lot of things just to include curl in my C project using the code::blocks ide but to no avail.

I would like to use cURL's library for my console app project that needs http capabilities.
If anyone had successfully done so, then your help is very much appreciated. :)

What happened previously:

-I copied all cURL files to my project and linked the libraries (the ones with .a or .lib ext.)

-Then when I build the project. A lot of undefined reference showed up.

This is the code I was testing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

    int main()
    {
     curl_global_init( CURL_GLOBAL_ALL );
     CURL * myHandle;
     CURLcode result; 
     myHandle = curl_easy_init ( ) ;

     curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com");
     result = curl_easy_perform( myHandle );
     curl_easy_cleanup( myHandle ); 
     printf("LibCurl rules!\n");
     return 0;
    }
```

Here are the errors:

```
||=== Fa, Release ===|
obj\Release\main.o:main.c|| undefined reference to `_imp__curl_global_init'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.c|| undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_init'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.c|| undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.c|| undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_perform'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.c|| undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_cleanup'|
||=== Build finished: 5 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

Comment: you need to actually tell us what the error is

Comment: It's a lot of "Undefined reference to <Function Name Here>"

Comment: You *include* it right, what you need is to *link* your program with appropriate version of libcurl.lib (or perhaps libcurl.a, dont't know for sure how Code Blocks works)

Comment: See my answer in another [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035360/codeblocks-and-lapack/9347181)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to your project "Build Options" -> "Linker" tab and so you have two choices:

1. If your library is (correctly) installed system-wide, write in "other linker options" the libs as if you were using your compiler directly.
   For GCC you'd write `-lcurl`. You may also use this with a path instruction like `Wl,-rpath,/path/to/your/library -lMyLib`. Obviously it depends on the compiler and system setup.
2. Add the library in "Link libraries" on the left. Click the "Add" button and browse to your library file.

Take a look at this [A.3 — Using libraries with Code::Blocks](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a3-using-libraries-with-codeblocks/) for some pictures.
Googling around will show you more.

Comment: -lcurl in "other linker options" worked for me on ubuntu
installed libcurl-dev (openssl) package.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The following steps are for windows 32 users. And the following steps worked for me after several hours. This may or may not work for you as I got it after several trial and errors. So thats why I am writing the steps in elaborate manner.

step1: start code blocks
create an empty project with name proj_curl

step2: Open on this url www.paehl.com/open_source/?CURL_7.50.0

- in this site download

a) click Download without ssl

b) click Download libcurl.dll (all versions) only

c) click Download the Libray (all version) only

step3: open on this url [curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.50.1.zip](https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.50.1.zip)
 - a zip file will be downloaded automatically.
(sorry folks this site is not allowing me to insert more than 2 links, bear with me.)

**Note:** Now Totally You have 4 zip files downloaded

1. curl_750_0.zip (which contains **curl.exe** file)
2. curl_DLL_ONLY.7z(which contains folders such as nossl, RTMP, ssh...etc.)
3. Curl_lib.7z(which contains **lib** folder)
4. curl-7.50.1.zip(which contains **curl-7.50.1** folder)

step4: create a folder in c drive(c:\libs\curl)
extract all the folders files of the 4 zip files into the curl folder in c.
Make sure to create each subdirectory for each zip file.

step5:(Very important)

In the curl folder of C drive,
- click on curl.exe(a command prompt just appears for few millisecs.)
- Go to code blocks -> Settings -> Compiler...  -> Linker settings tab -> Add

"C:\libs\curl\lib\nossl\libcurl.a"

"C:\libs\curl\lib\nossl\libcurldll.a"

then -> search directories tab -> Compiler
  [image]

then -> search directories tab -> Linker
   [image]

Click ok

Step6: 
- open the folder "nossl" which came in the curl_DLL_ONLY.7z file.

- copy the libcurl.dll file to the bin\debug folder of the code blocks project.

Step7: Now test the working of the curl library with your c program.

Note: if you encounter an error "The program cant start because zlib1.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem."

Solution: 
- copy and paste the url sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/latest/download

- install the mingw-get-setup.exe by marking all the libraries.(takes about 10 min to install)
- after installation, open C:\MinGW\bin, copy the zlib1.dll to the same directory as you did in step6 for libcurl.dll.

Thats it...