# Trying to use curl in codeblocks, getting a lot of "undefined reference" errors

Tags: c++, curl, codeblocks

I am trying to add curl into my project on codeblocks (windows 10). I have linked the .a files from libcurl in my linker settings, and I added the include file in my search directories. However, when I try to run the sample code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <json.hpp>
#include <curl/curl.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
    /* example.com is redirected, so we tell libcurl to follow redirection */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

    /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
   /* Check for errors */
   if(res != CURLE_OK)
     fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
          curl_easy_strerror(res));

  /* always cleanup */
  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

But Im still getting a bunch of errors (dont mind my user name)

```
||=== Build: Debug in LeagueAssistant (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `main':|
C:\Users\THE YUNG T-SCAGS\Desktop\programming            projects\LeagueAssistant\main.cpp|13|undefined reference to     `_imp__curl_easy_init'|
C:\Users\THE YUNG T-SCAGS\Desktop\programming projects\LeagueAssistant\main.cpp|15|undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'|
C:\Users\THE YUNG T-SCAGS\Desktop\programming projects\LeagueAssistant\main.cpp|17|undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'|
C:\Users\THE YUNG T-SCAGS\Desktop\programming projects\LeagueAssistant\main.cpp|20|undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_perform'|
C:\Users\THE YUNG T-SCAGS\Desktop\programming projects\LeagueAssistant\main.cpp|23|undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_strerror'|
C:\Users\THE YUNG T-SCAGS\Desktop\programming projects\LeagueAssistant\main.cpp|27|undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_cleanup'|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 7 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

Anyone have any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: Double check that you have added the .a correctly -- this is a link error.  If CodeBlocks has a verbose linker setting, turn it on.

Comment: Sorry to be a total newbie, but what does this mean? I'm not sure how else I would link the .a files. To be honest I'm not entirely sure what linking even means

Comment: You said "I have linked the .a files from libcurl in my linker settings" -- show us a screen shot of that.  There is compiled code inside the .a that implements curl.  Linking takes your compiled code and combines it with the libraries. "ld returned 1 exit status" is the linker reporting an error and the errors above indicate that it can't find the curl code.

Comment: here's a screenshot http://imgur.com/o0mhVmD

Comment: I would remove all of the lines that say .dll.a or dll.a, such that you only have libcurl.a, libz.a, libssl.a, etc -- if that doesn't work -- On the right hand side (the linker options pane), add `--verbose` and then post the build error after building with that setting.

Comment: I got this working using this answer from another question http://stackoverflow.com/a/38796443/7491922